# Using array_map with fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, pdo

I am creating json from my db as below;

```
$PdoObject -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$PdoStatement=$PdoObject->prepare($SqlQuery);
$PdoStatement->execute();
$PdoResultToArray=$PdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I am trying to working on value of db returned array as below but returns error.

```
$PdoResultToArrayNew=array_map("strtolower", $PdoResultToArray);
```

> Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: Your function `array_map(titleCase, $PdoResultToArray); ` must be like this `array_map("titleCase", $PdoResultToArray); `

Comment: Can you `print_r($PdoResultToArray)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$PdoResultToArray` is array of rows. Each row is array itself.

You must loop over each row manually:

```
foreach($PdoResultToArray as $row) {
    $json_row = array_map("strtolower", $row); 
    /// do with it what you want
}
```

Build new array with rows:

```
$lowerRows = []

foreach($PdoResultToArray as $row) {
    $lowerRows[] = array_map("strtolower", $row); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I merge arrays again after FOREACH like fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) structure?

Comment: Updated answer. Just create new array of rows.